# Mysql Subquery Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, subquery

I'm wondering why statements like `select * as t` appear in mysql subqueries like the following.

The following deletes the oldest 3 rows in a table according to a `created_time` column.

Why is this right

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = ANY 
( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 3')as t)
```

and not

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = ANY 
(SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 3)
```

?

To me, the second form makes sense. It doesn't work and I'd like to understand why the first is necessary. Specifically, what is `t` and what does `as t` do?

Comment: It's one of those stupid MySQL limitations. The second statement works for all other DBMS just fine. Even though the first one is accepted I recall some issues with it as well. You just can't use the table you are deleting from in a sub-select in MySQL, you need to use a join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Example of this workaround not working as expected: **[Problem with MySQL subquery](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery)**

Comment: @ypercube: thanks, that was exactly what I had in mind ;)

Comment: Mental image: You enter the Labyrinth and on your way - unlike Theseus - you chop the thread. Don't expect to come out safely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many databases, a subquery in a `from` clause needs to have an explicit alias.  The `as` is optional.  I typically use `as` for columns and leave it out for tables:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
    WHERE id = ANY ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY created_time ASC LIMIT 3') t)
```

Why you need the subquery is a vagary of MySQL.  It doesn't allow the table reference in a `delete` or `update` to appear in a subquery clause.  Oh, it does allow it in a subquery-within-a-subquery clause.  So, it is pretty easy to work around this limitation.